# Why does QDesktopWidget give me the wrong available geometry when I use two monitors in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

My application can work with two monitors and I want to detect monitor with Launcher bar (it can be on both monitors or only in one)
`QDesktopWidget` returns correct `screenGeometry(monitor_index)`, but if I use method `availableGeometry` it doesn't see Launcher bar on second monitor and returns incorrect value, but the Launcher bar is there.

```
QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();
QRect desktopGeometry = desktop->availableGeometry();
```

Is there a problem in Qt library, or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: This indeed seems to be a Qt bug, creating a bug report may be appropriate: https://bugreports.qt.io/